# geodatabase and relationship

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-database, python-2.6, relationship-class

I have two tables in a personal geodatabase and one of them has 13 records and 6 fields, the other has 118 records and 125 fields.

There is a relationship class between the two tables where the first table is the origin and the other (bigger) table is the destination.

What I need is to take the records satisfying a condition from the second table and sum those records and put into a new field in the origin table

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a 1-M relationship between the two tables:

1. Open up the attribute table for your big table
2. right-lick on the foreign key column, and select Summarize
3. Select the fields that you need to do your statistics on and the statistics method (sum, avg, etc).
4. It creates a new output table
5. Join the output table back to your origin table.
6. Open up the attribute table for your origin table.
7. Right-click on the destination field from your origin table and have it calc to your output table's column

Hope it helps.
JT